# When starting a thread my form gets locked

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a big data set that must be saved to database every 20 min.

What I want to do is creating a thread to do this work in the background, but instead by form gets locked.

```
var firstDate = DateTime.Now;
var finish = dateTimePicker1;
var next = firstDate.AddMilliseconds(10000);

while (true)
{        
      var now = DateTime.Now;
      var th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));

      cnt++;

      next = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10000);
      th.IsBackground = true;
      th.Start();
      hread.Sleep(20000);
      if (now==finish.Value)
      {
           break;
      }
}
MessageBox.Show("fi");
```

Why is my form locked and how to fix it?

Comment: That’s an infinite loop. Of course that will stop the UI from responding.

Comment: What is this project's type? Windows Form application? Is UI really that necessary to obtain the goal of this application? Or you may reconsider other type of project (e.g. Console Application with task scheduler, or SSIS package in SQL Server, or something else) ?

Answer (score 3):

A `while (true)` will run forever, so your form can't pick up any messages until the `while` loop is broken out from, which in your case is until the thread is done.

Instead of using a `Thread` I would recommend to use a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task` since those classes are easier in use. You can use the `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerCompleted` event for example to show a message to the user (don't forget to `Invoke`).

Comment: @user3480060: need more help?